# How to use inner join Using SQLAlchemy while utilizing query function

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

I am working on a project that requires me to join two tables. I have a table called Locations with a primary key of locationCode. A second table of trips, that holds two foreign keys of destination and origin. I would like to join the two tables together so that I may use Query object.

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = "locations"
    locationCode = Column(String(10), primary_key = True)
    latitude = Column(String(25))
    longitude = Column(String(25))
    FacilityOwnedByCarvana = Column(Integer)

class Trip(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trips"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    route = Column(String(25))
    origin_id = Column(String(10), ForeignKey("locations.locationCode"))
    destination_id = Column(String(10), ForeignKey("locations.locationCode"))
    origin = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[origin_id])
    destination = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[destination_id])
    weeklyCapacity = Column(Integer)
```

I have achieved what I needed using a raw query string

"select * from Locations as l left join Trips as t on l.locationCode = t.destination where l.locationCode='BALT' order by l.locationCode limit 10"

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
q = (
    session.query(Location)
    .outerjoin(Trip, Location.locationCode == Trip.destination_id)
    .filter(Location.locationCode == "BALT")
    .order_by(Location.locationCode)
    .limit(10)
)
```

*Because you have filter by `Location.locationCode`, `ORDER BY Location.locationCode` should not have any effect at all.*